# how to pass an argument in javascript making sure it's reference exists

Tags: javascript

I've see this done before, with something like `window.foo || {}` (which I know doesn't work), but I can't remember how this was done. I want to use it in this scenario:

```
(function(foo){
    foo.bar = "bar";
})(window.foo || {});
```

How do I do this?

Comment: (window.foo || (window.foo={}));

Comment: @Ibu The code doesn't contain syntax errors, but you won't be able to get `foo.bar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern I believe you are describing will check the global *window* object for a property `foo`.  If it is not found, it will default to the empty object.  You could assign a value to `window.foo` if you need some kind of default value instead of just an empty object:

`window.foo || (window.foo = "Gibberish and Goblins, oh my!")`

Comment: Ok, so I have to re=type window.foo? I thought there was a way of doing it with out that. Maybe not, I can't remember where i've seen it. Thanks

Comment: Even if there is a way to do it without retyping, I'd say being explicit in an assignment is more readable -- I'd still write it this way.

Comment: what if foo is `0, NaN, "", etc...` what will happen then

Comment: @ajax333221 You are correct, there are severe limitations with this answer.  The way Javascript handles "falsy" values bothers me deeply.  In the event that you think you'll encounter those values, I would write a helper method to check against any values that *you* want to consider false and use that instead of using the default check.

Answer (score 1):

You want this:

```
(function(foo){
    foo.bar = "bar";
})(window.foo || (window.foo = {}));
```

- Take `window.foo` if it exists and pass it as the parameter
- Or create a new object `window.foo` and pass that as the parameter